# How to do sum based on 2 elements using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to do summing of population per Timestamp & Reasoncode. It wasn't working, given the sample code below. Could you pls help me in making it working

My XML:

I have used the following XML as a Input file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Earnings>
    <Collection>
        <Timestamp>20170101</Timestamp>
        <Points>100</Points>
        <ReasonCode>AN</ReasonCode>
    </Collection>
    <Collection>
        <Timestamp>20170102</Timestamp>
        <Points>100</Points>
        <ReasonCode>AN</ReasonCode>
    </Collection>
    <Collection>
        <Timestamp>20170101</Timestamp>
        <Points>10000</Points>
        <ReasonCode>BP</ReasonCode>
    </Collection>
    <Collection>
        <Timestamp>20170101</Timestamp>
        <Points>10000</Points>
        <ReasonCode>BP</ReasonCode>
    </Collection>
    <Collection>
        <Timestamp>20170102</Timestamp>
        <Points>100</Points>
        <ReasonCode>PPTS</ReasonCode>
    </Collection>
</Earnings>
```

My XSLT

I have used the following XSLT used to convert my XML to designated format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:key name="Earnings" match="Earnings/Collection" use="concat(Timestamp, '+',ReasonCode)"/>
    <xsl:template match="Earnings">
        <Earnings>
            <xsl:for-each select="Collection[generate-id() = generate-id(key('Earnings', concat(Timestamp, '+',ReasonCode))[1])]">
                <xsl:sort select="concat(Timestamp, '+',ReasonCode)"/>
                <xsl:variable name="current-group" select="/Earnings/Collection[ReasonCode = current()/ReasonCode]"/>
                <Collection>
                    <Timestamp>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Timestamp"/>
                    </Timestamp>
                    <Points>
                        <xsl:value-of select="sum($current-group/Points)"/>
                    </Points>
                    <ReasonCode>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ReasonCode"/>
                    </ReasonCode>
                </Collection>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Earnings>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output

```
<Collection>
    <Timestamp>20170101</Timestamp>
    <Points>100</Points>
    <ReasonCode>AN</ReasonCode>
</Collection>
<Collection>
    <Timestamp>20170101</Timestamp>
    <Points>2000</Points>
    <ReasonCode>BP</ReasonCode>
</Collection>
<Collection>
    <Timestamp>20170102</Timestamp>
    <Points>100</Points>
    <ReasonCode>AN</ReasonCode>
</Collection>
<Collection>
    <Timestamp>20170102</Timestamp>
    <Points>100</Points>
    <ReasonCode>PPTS</ReasonCode>
</Collection>
```

Thanks,
Mohan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
<xsl:variable name="current-group" select="/Earnings/Collection[ReasonCode = current()/ReasonCode]"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:variable name="current-group" select="key('Earnings', concat(Timestamp, '+',ReasonCode))"/>
```

What you have now sums all the `Collection`s with the same `ReasonCode` as the current `Collection`, regardless of their `Timestamp`.